# Why doesn't the input's onclick event fire in this particular view?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a view and a form where the `onclick` event is not firing when the form is submitted for some reason.

This is the HTML:

```
<form class="form" method="post" novalidate>
  {% csrf_token %}

  <h1>{% block title %}{% trans "Form" %}{% endblock %}</h1>

  {% for field in form %}

    <div>
      <p>{{ field.help_text }}</p>
    </div>

    {{ field }}

    {% if field.errors %}
      <div class="error">
        {{ field.errors }}
      </div>
    {% endif %}

  {% endfor %}
  <br></br>

  <div class="bdiv">
    <input id="btn1" class="btn" type="submit" value="Submit"
      onclick="return confirm('Do you want to proceed?') && ajaxEvent();">
  </div>

</form>
```

This is a strange case because this exact markup works in all other views. I've double checked the rest of the html for typos, but there are none. The JQuery function works fine. Even if it wasn't the confirm alert should still display, but it doesn't.

The form just submits as if there is no `onclick`. However, if I put this `<div>` outside of the form tags, the `onclick` fires!

Why is this happening?

Comment: Try making the `div` tag a `form` tag and giving the form an `action="return confirm('Do you want to proceed?') && ajaxEvent();"` attribute.

Comment: Please provide more code so we have more context.

Comment: @VapporWashmade - added more code. Strange when I put it in a snippet it works, but not on my side.

Comment: @VapporWashmade - tried putting it in form tags, but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have assigned ajaxEvent function with return value and form is exists.

```
<form name="frm" action="success.html">
  <div class="bdiv">
    <input id="btn1" class="btn" type="submit" value="Submit"
      onclick="return confirm('Do you want to proceed?') && ajaxEvent();">
  </div>
 </form>
```

```
<script>
function ajaxEvent() {
    document.frm.submit();
    return true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Punitha, thanks, but I don't think it is to do with the function because it works in all other forms that I use it in. It just seems to be this particular view in question.

Comment: Which browser you are trying it?

Comment: Safari, but also shouldn't be the problem since the code works in other views.